# Python While loops - don't work BREAK

Tags: python, loops, arguments, break

I trying to create a simple game Tic Tac Toe. I'm a beginner in programming in Python.

The loop breaks when only 2 conditions are good. How to use this segment to 
meeting all conditions. That the loop breaks when all nastede1=X, nastede2=X and nastede3=X?

```
a=-1
while a <0:
    user_move()
    if ((nastede[1]==X) and (nastede[2]==X) and (nastede[3==X])):
        print("Game Over")
        break
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what `user_move()` does, and how are you storing the states of each cell in the grid? A list of lists? A 2D array?

Comment: What does `nastede` mean?  If you want international others to understand your code (for asking them how to fix it as you currently do), you need to make it understandable.  My advice would be:  Always use English terms for all names.

Comment: @Alfe well, it would mean something like "born of" or "from" in a few languages I know and I would rather OP left the names alone instead of changing them if it is not part of the problem - in this case it is a syntax error in the third condition. Maddie_Graham if the provided answer solves your problem you should accept it but this question may still be put on hold as it is a syntax error.

Comment: @JGreenwell Clean Code demands speaking names, and Maddie called herself a beginner.  I think such an advice is valid in general then ;-)  And actually, I think the code as it stands is no syntax error.  `3==X` will return a bool which is perfectly fine as an index, right?  It just is a bug of course as this is clearly not intended.  (If you want to put the Q on hold because of the simplicity of the bug, feel free.)

Comment: Maddie, I don't know if you can read the comments to the deleted answer you gave yourself (and which wasn't a proper answer) and in which you tried to ask followup questions.  This isn't how StackOverflow is supposed to work, that's why the answer got deleted.  Please walk through https://stackoverflow.com/tour to understand how this here works.  StackOverflow wants to be a _collection_ of useful questions and answers, so forum-like discussions are only allowed in comments, not in answers.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your syntax. Replace `(nastede[3==X])` with `(nastede[3]==X])`